# StableBaselines3 / PPO / model rollsout but does not learn?

Tags: python, tensorboard, stable-baselines

When a model *learns* there is:

1. A rollout phase
2. A learning phase

My models are *rolling out* but they never show a *learning phase*.  This is apparent both in the text output in a `jupyter Notebook` in `vscode` as well as in `tensorboard`.

I built a very simple `environment` and tried many more timesteps.  What I discovered was:

> If there are too few timesteps, the model never displays that it learns

- What is the minimum number of timesteps to learn?
- Is this the same for all environments or does it depend upon your environment?

```
import time

tic = time.perf_counter()

log_path = os.path.join('Training', 'Logs')
model = PPO("MlpPolicy", env, verbose=1, tensorboard_log=log_path)
modelRtn = model.learn(total_timesteps=1000, progress_bar=True)

toc = time.perf_counter()
print("Elapsed time:  " + str(toc-tic) + " sec")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PPO` has `n_steps` parameter that is 2048 by default. `collect_rollouts` fills the buffer until 2049-th iteration, then an execution returns to your `learn` method and stops immediately by reaching a limit of timesteps because you set only 1000 for the whole learning.

Comment: How did you figure that out?  

The `learn` method does not appear to have this in the documentation:  https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/ppo.html  I see that PPO has a method for `collect_rollouts`.  So, you can't set this value in `learn`... you must set it in `collect_rollouts`?

What is the best way for me to learn these details?  I certainly want to learn faster than an AI algorithm...